# Lyrics following a song in the same time as It listened

Tags: php

I want to do something which is maybe special. I have a song, and I have It's lyrics, what I want to do is that a method to provide the opportunity to the lyrics to follow the song, for example I listen to the song in the same time I read the lyrics which show what I have just heard.

Comment: PHP is server-side.  Chances are, you're looking for something client-side, like Javascript, Flash, Silverlight etc.

Comment: What are you using to play the song file?

Comment: Yes, maybe It will be by javascript.
@Phoenix I use an mp3 flash player

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting up the lyrics by when they appear in the song.  E.g.:

```
$lyrics['when_im_gone'] = array(
  12.5 => 'There\'s another world inside of me that you may never see',
  19.5 => 'There\'re secrets in this life that I can\'t hide',
  26.0 => 'Somewhere in this darkness there\'s a light that I can\'t find',
  31.5 => 'Maybe it\'s too far away...',
  37.5 => 'Or maybe I\'m just blind...'
);
```

In the above array, the first lyric should be displayed at 12.5 seconds in, the second at 19.5, etc.

In your Flash audio player, request the array from the server (or use PHP to inject the array into the page markup when it loads), and then display each lyric at its appointed time in the song.

Comment: But by following your method I should add timing and lyrics in around 6 seconds ! Usually in songs we listen every 5 or 6 seconds to a phrase on the lyrics, so it's seems to me that is pretty impossible to use it !

Comment: The example I posted is just an example; you can use a shorter/longer interval if you want; add fewer/more lyrics to each array element.